# Woocommerce - filter by featured products in admin

Tags: php, woocommerce

Since version 3.0 Woocommerce removed sorting option for featured products on the backend. I tried this solution here but it seems to be not working any more https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104537/woocommerce-filter-by-featured-products-in-admin

It created nice dropdown filters but unfortunately is not filtering Featured products.

Since we have more than 2000 products it is very tidious to seek them one by one. Is there a way to sort or filter our featured products?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Add custom sorting options (Featured)
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'featured';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['featured'] = 'Featured';
    return $sortby;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here is the code which seems to be working and as a bonus you can filter out of stock products and rated products

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'featured_products_sorting');
function featured_products_sorting() {
    global $typenow;
    $post_type = 'product'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'product_visibility'; // change to your taxonomy
    if ($typenow == $post_type) {
        $selected      = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) ? $_GET[$taxonomy] : '';
        $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
            'show_option_all' => __("Show all {$info_taxonomy->label}"),
            'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
            'name'            => $taxonomy,
            'orderby'         => 'name',
            'selected'        => $selected,
            'show_count'      => true,
            'hide_empty'      => true,
        ));
    };
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'featured_products_sorting_query');
function featured_products_sorting_query($query) {
    global $pagenow;
    $post_type = 'product'; // change to your post type
    $taxonomy  = 'product_visibility'; // change to your taxonomy
    $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset($q_vars['post_type']) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && is_numeric($q_vars[$taxonomy]) && $q_vars[$taxonomy] != 0 ) {
        $term = get_term_by('id', $q_vars[$taxonomy], $taxonomy);
        $q_vars[$taxonomy] = $term->slug;
    }
}
```